# Checksum to edit profile not working?

Tags: profile, tokens, checksum

I've been trying to test using checksums to access pre-filled Profiles, eg:

```
/civicrm/profile/edit?gid=1&cid=12&cs=12f12df65c25b4b31afb11726af4d5ca_1438265969_168
```

However it does not seem to be working in the current version of CiviCRM (4.6.x). The profile appears without any information filled, and there are no error messages displayed.

Using the same approach (same contact ID and checksum) to pre-fill an event form is working fine, eg:

```
/civicrm/event/register?id=442&reset=1&cid=12&cs=12f12df65c25b4b31afb11726af4d5ca_1438265969_168
```

Is anyone else experiencing the same problem? If so I'll submit a bug report.

Documentation for checksums at the bottom of this page: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Tokens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that for profile edit, you need to use `id` rather than `cid` for the contact id, as per the docs you linked to:

http://www.myorganization.org/civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=N&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}

Comment: Doh! RTM. Hooray for CiviCRM's consistency there though :P Thanks davejenx.